# Webservice keyword

Tags: webservices

While exposing apex class as SOAP web service, we declare the class as global and include a method with keyword Webservice and static. However in few scenarios I have seen few instance variable as are too declared with keyword WebService. What are the extra advantages to such variables?

Comment: Can you edit your question and define what you mean by the phrases "instance variable" and "string variable as argument". The answer below by @Moshe is correct but we can probably clarify the response by knowing more detail. **Even better,** if you can add some code to demonstrate which variables you are referring to, that would help very much.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs : You must use the webService keyword with any member variables that you want to expose as part of a Web service.

You can read more over here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods_considerations.htm

Comment: I went to that doc before posting this question, but I still have a doubt. In one of my Webservice I take String variable as argument and is not defined with WebService keyword, but that is still working. Hence i wanted to know what does " expose as part of Web Service means".